# nslookup or developer for pages that link to a website

Tags: hyperlink, html, nslookup

Is there an nslookup command that will allow me to find all associated pages to a given website? I want to find all pages that link to www.google.com, how can I find that information?

Comment: `nslookup` is an OS tool that isn't capable of parsing HTML to find hyperlinks. You may need a web crawler, or something similar to http://wummel.github.io/linkchecker/ to look for specific links on a site.

Comment: That gave me pages to the actual website. Like www.google.com/edu

Comment: So for example, www.google.com has plus.google.com, drive.google.com, etc. I want all of these pages that link to the google.com.

Comment: So you're looking for subdomains, in that case we can look for DNS information with something like: https://dnsdumpster.com/

Comment: That site won't return anything for google.com

Comment: Do you know the nslookup command for that? I know there is one, I can't for the life of me remember what it is.